# Access denied while getting favorite sites from SharePoint Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, client-object-model, csom

I am trying to get favorite sites of a user from SharePoint Online using CSOM. I am creating a ClientContext first using an access token and then trying to get the favorite sites using below code:

```
        try
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = this.GetSharePointClientContext(accessToken);
            SocialFollowingManager followingManager = new SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);               

            // Get the count of sites that the current user is following.
            ClientResult<int> followedSiteCount = followingManager.GetFollowedCount(SocialActorTypes.Sites);

            // Get the sites that the current user is following.
            ClientResult<SocialActor[]> followedSiteResult = followingManager.GetFollowed(SocialActorTypes.Sites);

            // Get the information from the server.
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {               
            throw;
        }
```

I am not able to find the root cause of this issue. Everything else seem to be working fine except getting favorite sites. Need help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in my local, it’s working.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Lee"))
        {
            string password = "pw";
            SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
            Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
            sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("lee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);

            SocialFollowingManager followingManager = new SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);

            // Get the count of sites that the current user is following.
            ClientResult<int> followedSiteCount = followingManager.GetFollowedCount(SocialActorTypes.Sites);

            // Get the sites that the current user is following.
            ClientResult<SocialActor[]> followedSiteResult = followingManager.GetFollowed(SocialActorTypes.Sites);

            // Get the information from the server.
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is with the use of access token in ClientContext. Have you verified the above with a ClientContext created using access token?